# Rebar get-deps does not play well with msysgit 1.7.4 on Windows

Tags: windows, git, erlang, rebar

Has anyone been successful with using rebar get-deps on Windows? Mine fails and complains about version numbers.

If you have been successful, which git did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebar get-deps **works** on Windows. But:

1. bash.exe must **not** be in the PATH, so don't choose this option when install msysgit. Rebar thinks that cygwin is here but it is not :(
2. Rename git.cmd to git.bat in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\. It is ugly hack but it seems that erl.exe can execute only exe and bat files not cmd

Comment: I'll need to try this out. Great answer.

Comment: Same problem, but this didn't help. My git executable is already a git.exe under /bin.

Comment: And bash.exe is right here in /bin too. So C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ MUST not be in the PATH or rebar will not work.

Answer (score 2):

[rebar](https://bitbucket.org/basho/rebar/) (an Erlang build and packaging tool by [Dave Smith](http://twitter.com/dizzyco), used by the [Nitrogen project](http://nitrogenproject.com/)) doesn't seem to work well for Windows at the moment:

```
lang/erlang/nitrogen>make rel_inets
./rebar get-deps
==> rel (get-deps)
==> nitrogen (get-deps)
Pulling nitrogen_core from {git,"https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen_core.git",
                                "HEAD"}
ERROR: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c 
         ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" --version; echo _port_cmd_status_ $?"  
       failed with error: 127
make: *** [get-deps] Error 1
```

This thread [doubt it works on Windows at all](http://groups.google.com/group/nitrogenweb/browse_thread/thread/4ce873aee9a4111f).
This [recent irc trasncript](http://irclogger.com/.riak/2011-08-02) mentions:

> `<Thesolonius>`
>   and rebar generate of an application creates a bash script that we can't seem to run.
>   makes me wonder if our understanding of the correct setup environment is incorrect?
>   in our release, the script can't find "`run_erl`"
>   and we cannot find "`run_erl`" anywhere on the box
>   the same code runs just fine in linux
>
> `<drev1>`
>   perhaps that needs to be `run_erl.exe/`
>
> `<Thesolonius>`
>   there's no `run_erl.*`
>
> `<drev1>`
>   oh hmm
>
> `<Thesolonius>`
>   there's a start_erl.exe
>   but, if that name was the problem, it suggests rebar isn't targeting windows
>   during the "generate" command?
>   Which would lead me to ask if rebar can be given a hint as to it's current platform?
>
> `<drev1>`
>   I'm not sure how much work has been done with rebar on windows
>   looks like `start_erl` is the Windows equivalent of `run_erl`
>   10:29  but it seems to take different command line arguments
>
> `<Thesolonius>`
>   that's what we found too
>
> `<drev1>`
>   my guess is you would need a Windows specific template for release generation
>   rather than the create-node template that ships with rebar